# siunitx v3 replacement for `detect-all`

Tags: siunitx

I have a document where figure captions are set sans serif. Section headings are bold. Both do contain the occasional unit, so I have been using the `detect-all` option with `siunitx`.

I just now discovered that according to the [official changelog](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#removed) all the `detect-*` options got removed in `siunitx` v3. Well, technically it seems like they are still working, but at least they have been deprecated, and they are no longer documented.

What is the intended replacement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: there isn't currently one.

In v2 (and v1) of `siunitx`, I used an approach based on an older package (`sistyle`). This means resetting *everything* to a known position, then adding detected changes as requested. There are a few issues with that. The first is it's relatively 'expensive' in TeX terms: we always have to do at least the reset and possibly more. The second is that it means I need to *know* what to look for to detect/reset. That leads to some issues. The approach is reflected in the option names: `detect-...` as that's what happens.

In v3, the approach is different. I only alter as many things as are required to match the user request. That is less work, it means I don't have to know what every possible change is, and it reflects the fact that math and text modes work differently. The downside is that I can't find a good name for all of the settings together.

The older `detect-all` is emulated by applying

```latex
mode = match ,
propagate-math-font = true ,
reset-math-version = false ,
reset-text-family = false ,
reset-text-series = false ,
text-family-to-math = true ,
text-series-to-math = true
```

but as you'll see there's no obvious name here. Notice that in some edge cases it won't do the same as in v2: that's why there is a fallback to load v2 as an option.

As such, you will need to set explicitly those font-control options you want to active.