# siunitx renders numerical value in different font than unit

Tags: siunitx, sans-serif

I am trying to render figure captions in a sans-serif font.

I have gotten as far as setting up the caption package to use the sf font for text (easy) and math (via the `sansmath` package).

I am struggling to make `siunitx` fit into this. `\SI` or `\qty` will render the *number* in the serif'ed font.

This is sort of a [follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/612238/122397). Note that I am using all of `siunitx`'s switches to detect math mode, font family etc.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{sansmath}

\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true, multi-part-units=single]{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    mode = match,
    propagate-math-font = true ,
    reset-math-version = false ,
    reset-text-family = false ,
    reset-text-series = false ,
    text-family-to-math = true ,
    text-series-to-math = true
}

\parindent=0in

\begin{document}
\sansmath
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    1. Plain serif text:            & 123\,m                 \\
    \sffamily 2. Plain sans math:   & $123\,m$               \\ 
    \sffamily 3. Plain sans text:   & \sffamily 123\,m       \\
    \sffamily 4. siunitx sans text: & \sffamily\qty{123}{m}   \\
    \sffamily 5. siunitx sans math: & \sffamily$\qty{123}{m}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

I understand what is going on in all but the last one. Why are the figures serif'ed?

PS: BTW, if I leave out the last `\sffamily` then also the unit is set with serifs.

Comment: Okay, it seems to work as expected if I leave out the `text-series-to-math` option. Makes no sense to me though.

Comment: Do not be deterred from posting an answer by my previous comment. It is not the solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observe, this comes about with `text-series-to-math` active. To understand what's happening, you need to know two things

- Math mode and text mode work very differently in terms of fonts; in particular, the `\mathversion` is used to set `\sansmath` (a shape) as well as for example `\boldmath` (a series).
- In v3, `siunitx` aims to format quantities to a 'standard' form, which looks like `123\,\mathrm{m}` here, then applies transformations to get the desired output.

That leads to an odd outcome here as `text-series-to-math` finds that the text *series* is medium, so sets the `\mathversion`, but that zaps `\sansmath`. On the other hand, the part of the code that deals with `\mathrm` does stay active so uses `\mathsf`, and so the unit is unaffected.

I will think if there is any way to make this clearer or to better separate the different aspects of math version.

---

For the present, if you set

```latex
\sisetup{series-version-mapping / m = sans}
```

then things should be 'ok'.

Comment: I have a fix for this that will appear in v3.0.29: it goes with a few other things so I won't try to post a patch - expect an update in a day or so.